# Is it possible to chain two consecutive find commands?

Tags: find, performance

I want to:

- find all directories that start with a capital letter
- then, find all directories named '.git' in those directories

This is for performance optimization. It's my solution to reduce the search scope to specific directories first, then search inside them.

For the first one, I have this in mind:

```
find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "[[:upper:]]*"
```

And for the second one, I was using:

```
find / -type d -name ".git" 2>/dev/null
```

Now I don't know how to chain them together. I want the second `find` to only search in the results of the first `find`.

Or if it's an X-Y problem, please tell me your suggestions to increase the speed.

I require to find all `.git` directories on a machine. But it's guaranteed that `.git` directories are all inside top-level directories that start with a capital letter.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you can do it with one `find` expression and even avoid the `-mindepth` / `-maxdepth` GNUisms with:

```
find / ! -path / ! -path '/[[:upper:]]*' -prune -o -name .git -type d -print
```

More generally, you can chain `find` commands portably with:

```
find ... -exec sh -c '
  find "$@" ... -exec ... {\} ...' sh {} +
```

(here showing how to insert a `{}` for the inner (second) find to avoid it being picked up by the outer (first) one).

Or with recent versions of GNU `find` (4.9.0 or above):

```
find ... -print0 | find -files0-from - ...
```

Comment: I didn't understand the first single `find` you wrote. It says `not /` and `not uppercase`? The second `!` is for uppercase? And can you please explain what `-prune` does here?

Answer (score 4):

Since the first `find` is only searching a single level, you can replace it with a simple shell wildcard pattern: `/[[:upper:]]*`. Then use that as the places for `find` to search:

```
find /[[:upper:]]* -type d -name ".git" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It does not work.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I don't have a setup to test it exactly (i.e. with uppercase top-level directories), but with subdirs and `./[[:upper:]]*` it works as expected. If it's not working for you, I'd try replacing `find` with `echo`, and make sure the wildcard is expanding properly. If that's not the problem, remove the `2>/dev/null` and see if any errors are informative.